# Linear regression on non-normal response with categorical predictors

Tags: regression, categorical-data, residuals

I am trying to define a model for an experiment comparing 3 groups of samples, with 8 observations in each group. The purpose is to assess if observations in groups 2 and 3 are smaller than in group 1, and if so, how much.

From the biological background  of the experiment the response is supposed to be log-normally distributed (log10). However one cannot assume as much with this few observations.

As one can see on group 2, the response is significantly non-normal (`shapiro.test` in `R` reports p=0.01519093).

These are the histograms for the log10-transformed responses on groups 1:3.

[image]

For this reason, I opted not to do a one-way ANOVA (or Kruskal-Wallis) test. Instead I am modelling as `log10 (y) ~ Group` in R.

As I understand it, the important assumption of regression is in the residuals and *not* the response. Below is the residuals plots from `R`, where there seems to be such an issue with group 2.

[image]

**What would be a sound regression strategy here?**

- Should I do another transformation on the data to try to address the non-normality of residuals in group 2? If so, would it change the interpretation of coefficients?
- Should I use ANOVA instead of regression in this situation, maybe with some other considerations applicable?

Comment: Anova and regression are the same second option will not be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What second option do you refer to?